# How to reduce IF statements for multiple option buttons

Tags: excel, vba

I have a UserForm which lets the user input a count of product defects into a textbox. This is done as part of monthly reporting, so I have option buttons to select the Month (12 options). There are also option buttons for selecting Product Type. The code basically evaluates what options are selected and copies the textbox values (defect counts) into specific cells in another spreadsheet (for reporting purposes). Not all TextBoxes are required to have values entered by the User.

You can check out a screenshot of the UserForm https://i.stack.imgur.com/PB96W.jpg.

As you can see from the code, I'm using a bunch of IF statements to perform the decision making - I would like to reduce the length of this code, but I don't know where to start.

I have never really used VBA prior to this, so haven't really attempted a solution. In its current state, the code works flawlessly. Just looking to reduce and clean-up.

```
Private Sub OKButton_Click() 'This is the button the user clicks to finalize
                             'the data entry

'Calling the Product type modules
Call Product1Module
Call Product2Module
Call Product3Module

End Sub
```

```
Sub Product1Module() 'All product modules will look almost exactly like this
                     'except the cell ranges will be different

If UserForm.Product1Button.Value = True Then 'Checking for Product1 Option button
    If UserForm.JANButton.Value = True Then
    'Record value to textbox if JAN is selected
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1107").Value = UserForm.TextBox1.Value
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1115").Value = UserForm.TextBox2.Value
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1108").Value = UserForm.TextBox3.Value
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1116").Value = UserForm.TextBox4.Value
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1109").Value = UserForm.TextBox5.Value
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1117").Value = UserForm.TextBox6.Value
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1111").Value = UserForm.TextBox7.Value
    ElseIf UserForm.FEBButton.Value = True Then
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C1107").Value = UserForm.TextBox1.Value
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C1115").Value = UserForm.TextBox2.Value
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C1108").Value = UserForm.TextBox3.Value
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C1116").Value = UserForm.TextBox4.Value
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C1109").Value = UserForm.TextBox5.Value
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C1117").Value = UserForm.TextBox6.Value
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C1111").Value = UserForm.TextBox7.Value
    ...

    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Do the rows stay the same and only the column changes depending on the month?

Comment: Yes, only columns will change.

Comment: Name your textboxes, urgently.

Comment: The `If` should then only choose the column; move the actual writing of values to the end.

Comment: Better suited for [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) if indeed the code works flawlessy.

Answer (score 2):

Give each of your option buttons a `Tag` property value - e.g. make `JANButton.Tag` be "B", then make `FeBButton.Tag` be "C", etc.

Then you can do this:

```
Dim targetColumn As String
Select Case True
    Case UserForm.JANButton
        targetColumn = UserForm.JANButton.Tag
    Case UserForm.FEBButton
        targetColumn = UserForm.FEBButton.Tag
    '...
End Select
With Worksheets("Sheet1") '<~ which workbook is that in? whatever is active?
    .Range(targetColumn & "1107").Value = UserForm.TextBox1.Value
    .Range(targetColumn & "1115").Value = UserForm.TextBox2.Value
    '...
End With
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Going to give it a shot and will return with feedback. Oh and the "Sheet1" is actually pointing to an adjacent tab in the same workbook, I just needed to scrub the specific name before I posted my question :)

Comment: @JTigs355 if the sheet is in `ThisWorkbook`, give it a meaningful/descriptive `(Name)` property and use that identifier in your code instead of dereferencing it from the `Sheets` collection every time you need it.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon - Maybe this isn't the forum for this question, but I installed RD on Windows 10; XL 2016 (64 bit) and excel wasn't very happy about it. I haven't researched it to much, bc I got busy, but does it support 64 bit OS? Or am I SOL?

Comment: Thanks @MathieuGuindon. I will open a ticket. "not very happy about it" stood for Excel kept crashing unmercifully directly after I installed RubberDuck on my machine. To be able to offer a more meaningful support ticket, I will download and install again and if the issues persist, I will send concrete (as I can) feedback.